# Power BI - How to create new column that summarize data by week and by Online or Store Channel?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have WTDdata table that contains ThisYearRevenue and LastYearRevenue summarized by week:

[image]

I need to create 4 more columns LastYearOnlineRevenue, LastYearStoreRevenue, ThisYearOnlineRevenue, and ThisYearStoreRevenue from another  table (RevenueByDate) that looks like this:

[image]

W column in this table means Fiscal Week.

I tried using this aproach:

```
    LastYearOnlineRevenue = 
    SUMMARIZE(FILTER(ALL(FiscalCalendar),FiscalCalendar[FiscalWeek]),FiscalCalendar[FiscalWeek]),
    "LastYearOnlineRevenue",CALCULATE(SUM(RevenueByDate[Revenue]),FiscalCalendar[FiscalYear] = 
    YEAR(TODAY())-1 && RevenueByDate[Channel] = "Online")
```

If you can help me with at least one column, I am assuming the logic will be the same for the other 3.
Thank you in advance.

Here is the location for sample data and .pbix file:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhhZq1add5YwjYIvuASi76lCL3R1eA?e=C7ObDZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Since there is no way of telling the current year from the WTDdata table, I have assumed that the current year is always 2021, you can also replace that with:

VALUE ( MAX ( RevenueByDate[FiscalYear] ) )

```
LastYearOnlineRevenue =
VAR CurrentFiscalWeek = WTDdata[FiscalWeek]
VAR CurrentYear = 2021
VAR ImmediatePreviousYear =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( FiscalCalendar[FiscalYear] ),
        FiscalCalendar[FiscalYear] < CurrentYear,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( WTDdata )
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( RevenueByDate[Revenue] ),
        FiscalCalendar[FiscalWeek] = CurrentFiscalWeek,
        FiscalCalendar[FiscalYear] = ImmediatePreviousYear,
        RevenueByDate[Channel] = "Online",
        REMOVEFILTERS ( WTDdata )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: Awesome, this will work. Thank you so much Antrik